# Type is missing the following properties from type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I got this message

> Class 'Motorvoertuig' incorrectly implements interface 'Voertuig'.
>   Type 'Motorvoertuig' is missing the following properties from type
>   'Voertuig': toonMerk, wieIsDeEigenaar

But I really don't know why?

I have more code in this document but the error comes from the following Methodes.

```
interface Voertuig {
     merk: string;
    eigenaar: string;

    toonMerk(merk:string);
    wieIsDeEigenaar(eigenaar:string);
};
abstract class Motorvoertuig implements Voertuig {
  (Some code)
}
```

How to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

You have marked `Motorvoertuig` as implementing `Voertuig` interface that means you need to add all fields present in `Voertuig` interface to `Motorvoertuig` class.
So for example:

```
abstract class Motorvoertuig implements Voertuig {
  merk: string = '';
  eigenaar: string = '';
  toonMerk(merk: string) {}
  wieIsDeEigenaar(eigenaar: string) {}
}
```

or you can try using something like:

```
abstract class Motorvoertuig implements Partial<Voertuig> {
}
```

check [advanced typescript types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you implement an interface, you need to define the properties that are declared in the interface. In `Motorvoertuig`, you probably have defined `merk` and `eigenaar`, but not `toonMerk` and `wieIsDeEigenaar`.

If you don't want to implement those methods inside your abstract class `Motorvoertuig`, you can make the methods abstract like this:

```
abstract toonMerk(merk: string);
abstract wieIsDeEigenaar(merk: string);
```